# How to use roomHint and structureHint with smarthome actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

We are currently setting un a Smarthome action, and we would like to provide `roomHint` on the first sync (not on request sync) as it's really tedious to set up rooms on the first sync, but it does not work.

We tried to name rooms in english and also in italian, (as it's not really clear from the documentation if there is a list on room names that we can use?) but no way.

So can you please give us a hint how to use the `roomHint` field?

Also in the API doc we've found `structureHint`, does it work? The documentation for SYNC intent does not mention this field.

Here is our SYNC intent with one device and room, we took office from the example JSON:

```
{  
  "requestId": "3582198904737125163",
    "payload": {
        "agentUserId": "xyz@qwertyz.com",
        "devices": [
            {
                "id": "deviceID",
                "type": "action.devices.types.LIGHT",
                "traits": [
                    "action.devices.traits.OnOff"
                ],
                "name": {
                    "name": "Lampadina",
                    "defaultNames": [
                        "Lampadina_XYZ"
                    ],
                    "nicknames": [
                        "Lampadina"
                    ]
                },
                "willReportState": false,
                "customData": {
                    "modelType": "DEVICE"
                },
                "roomHint": "office"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by room hint not working? Do other rooms beyond "office" act the same? Are these rooms that the user has already set up?

Comment: By not working i mean that after the initial sync, when the screen with all of the devices open, we expected to find the devices divided by rooms. But it did not happen. What should be the expected behavior of roomHint field? We tried with several rooms, not only office. We tried also with pre created rooms and with no rooms at all, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe the `structureHint` is only in the HomeGraph API sync response.

It cannot be used in the Sync intent.

If someone can tell me I'm wrong and how to use it, you'd be a hero.